# How many products do I have Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a table whit some products and I try to do that if I add more products than I have in my inventory it has to show me an alert.

I did it but its not working, In products i have the sku and reference.In inventories i have all the products that i have.

Controller:

```
foreach ($request->dataTable as $dataTable) {
    $productId = DB::table('products')
        ->where('sku', $dataTable[2])
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->select('id', 'reference')
        ->first();
    $inventoryId = DB::table('inventories')
        ->where('product_id', $productId->id)
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->whereNull('sale_id')
        ->select('id')
        ->first();

    if ($inventoryId == null) {
        return response()->json([
            'type' => 'error',
            'msg'  => 'No existe suficiente stock para realizar la venta del producto con referencia: ' . $productId->reference . '. Solo hay ' . $productId->references->count(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Product Model:

```
public function references()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Inventory');
}
```

Products

| id | reference | sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BCR2214 | 0108888893016580 |
| 2 | BCR2219 | 0108888893016580 |

Inventories

| ID | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

If I add a product_id = 1 three times it has to show me the alert and says "The product 1 only has 2 in stock in inventory"
But I add two products and says: **"error", msg: "Undefined property: stdClass::$references"}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not able to access eloquent relationships on the DB facade.

If you wanted to access the `references` relationship you'd need to change

```
$productId = DB::table('products')
        ->where('sku', $dataTable[2])
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->select('id', 'reference')
        ->first();
```

into an eloquent model lookup, something like

```
$productId = App\Models\Products::where('sku', $dataTable[2])
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->select('id', 'reference')
        ->first();
```

---

As a separate note and to help with performance, I'd also suggest eager loading the `inventories` relationship. Without knowing much about your DB design, something like the below should get you started

```
//   Product model
public function inventories()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Inventory');
}
```

Then you could adjust the top eloquent query to be something like

```
$productId = App\Models\Products::where('sku', $dataTable[2])
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->doesntHave('inventories')
        ->select('id', 'reference')
        ->first();
```

---

Be sure to checkout [Laravel eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships) for more information specific to your situation